# Calling functions from main in C

Tags: c, function

I have a problem regarding calling functions in C from main,I think I have this problem because I still don't get used to the procedural language but I can't figure this out at all.The error is "number undeclared(first use in this function)" and "number2 undeclared(first use in this function)".

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

 int add(int number,int number2){
  int answer;
  answer = number + number2;

  printf("Enter a number\n");
  scanf("%d",&number);

  printf("Enter another number\n");
  scanf("%d",&number2);

   printf("The result of those numbers are %d\n",answer);
}



int main()
{
    add(number,number2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Within each function, the compiler processes statements from top to bottom, and the CPU will execute statements from top to bottom.  Each variable must be both declared and assigned a value before it is used.  Declaring a variable within, or as part of the argument list of, one function, does not make it available for use in any other functions.  Do you now see what you have done wrong?

Comment: I thought C was smart enough to know that answer = number + number2 therefore add(number,number2) is answer.

Comment: How is C suppose to know what number1 and number2 are? Do you expect the compiler to miracle  a value to them?

Comment: No, `C` is easy to express algorithms in, but it doesn't interpret programmer's intent.  It (maddeningly) does exactly what you tell it to do.

Comment: There are programming languages in which you return a value from a function by assigning it to a special variable (Fortran comes to mind) but I don't know of any programming languages in which you can call a function with arguments that aren't in scope in the caller and it will Do What You Meant as expressed in a completely different place.

Comment: (Of course now I've said that someone else is practically guaranteed to point out an example.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Part 1: You need to have variables declared before you use them.

In your main you do this `add(number,number2);` but how does main know what your variables are? You need to declare them:

```
int number, number2;
```

### Part 2: Make your functions simple

You want a function to add 2 numbers, so that is what the function should do:

```
int add(int number1, int number2) {
    return number1 + number 2;
}
```

### Part 3: Lets take some user input and add them

You shouldnt have your add function taking your user input, either make a new function like:

```
int getNumberFromUser(const char *promptText) {
    int userInput;
    printf("%s:", promptText);
    scanf("%d", &userInput);
    return userInput;
 }
```

Or just get them in main:

```
int main() {
  // Declare your numbers.
  int answer;
  int number1, number2;

  // Get input from the user.
  printf("Enter a number\n");
  scanf("%d",&number);
  printf("Enter another number\n");
  scanf("%d",&number2);

  // Add them together:
  answer = add(number1, number2);

  // Tell the user.
  printf("The result of those numbers are %d\n",answer);
}
```

[Here is a live example.](http://ideone.com/ist9HV)

Comment: Thanks it worked I had started java(but never finished it)and I got drilled into my head some object oriented programming but I guess everything is procedural so C is alittle bit more dumb or needs more specific tasks.

Comment: @firefly23: This is not different in Java. Maybo you missed a lesson or two?

Comment: So you're saying C is object oriented programming?Correct me if im wrong but in java or C++ you could have functions communicating with each other and print them out using objects.So one function would set the values and statements,the other function would return it and the last one would be the prompt to the user.

Comment: @firefly23 use @ "name" to notify a person. Olaf wont see this message.

Comment: @Olaf So you're saying C is object oriented programming?Correct me if im wrong but in java or C++ you could have functions communicating with each other and print them out using objects.So one function would set the values and statements,the other function would return it and the last one would be the prompt to the user. –

Comment: @firefly23: Although you can very well OOP in C, I didn't say that. But you have to declare a name before accessing it. And note that Java & C++ also follow a procedural/imperative paradigm. This in contrast to functional, where you can also use OOP techniques.

Answer (score 2):

Change your main function to declare the variables there, like this:

```
int main() 
{
    int number = 1, number2 = 2;
    add(number,number2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I actually want to retrieve user input so thats a no no.Thats what im tryna figure out.

Comment: @firefly23 Do you want to return the number to your main function or just print the result?

Comment: @firefly23 Do you know how to retrieve user input *without* extra functions?

Answer (score 0):

C requires you to "declare" each variable before you use it.  This involves a statement that specifies at least the variable's name and its type.  For instance:

```
int number;
```

Your compiler is complaining that you have not done this for either `number` or `number1`.

Additionally, for the behavior of your program to be defined, you must assign a value to each variable before you use it.  For example,

```
number = 1;
```

You do not do this, either, but although the compiler likely will warn you about that if you do not correct it, it likely will also be happy to *do what you said* and produce a program that exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

this code is really not correct

```
int add(int number,int number2){
  int answer;
  answer = number + number2;

  printf("Enter a number\n");
  scanf("%d",&number);

  printf("Enter another number\n");
  scanf("%d",&number2);

   printf("The result of those numbers are %d\n",answer);
}
```

It accepts two numbers as input to the function. Adds them, then asks the user 2 enter some numbers and displays the result of adding the numbers passed int the  function call

YOu mean either:

```
int add(){
  int answer, number,numer2;

  printf("Enter a number\n");
  scanf("%d",&number);

  printf("Enter another number\n");
  scanf("%d",&number2);

   printf("The result of those numbers are %d\n",answer);
}
```

or

```
int add(int number,int number2){
  int answer;
  answer = number + number2;



   printf("The result of those numbers are %d\n",answer);
}
```

and put the prompting in main

```
main()
{
int number,number2;
  printf("Enter a number\n");
  scanf("%d",&number);

  printf("Enter another number\n");
  scanf("%d",&number2);
  add(number,number2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need conio.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <conio.h>

int add(int number,int number2) {
    return number + number2;
}

int main()
{
    int answer;
    int number, number2 = 0;

    printf("Enter a number\n");
    scanf("%d",&number);

    printf("Enter another number\n");
    scanf("%d",&number2);

    answer = add(number,number2);

    printf("The result of those numbers are %d\n",answer);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several misconceptions present in your code.

First, the parameters to `add()` are not used as parameters.  They are used as local variables.  Instead, write the function explicitly indicating that:

```
int add()
{
  int answer, number, number2;
  ...
```

Secondly, `answer` is computed from the parameters, not from the values read.  While that is computationally valid, it is confusing.  What do you want this logic to really do?  Here, I have moved the *answer* computation to after the inputs are read:

```
  printf("Enter a number\n");
  scanf("%d", &number);

  printf("Enter another number\n");
  scanf("%d", &number2);

  answer = number + number2;
  printf("The result of those numbers are %d\n",answer);
```

This ignores the parameters originally passed to `add()`.